# Creating FLIRT Signature Files for new CPU

Tags: ida, flirt-signatures

I have writen a new processor module for M-CORE CPU, now i want to generate FLIRT Signature Files for this cpu. 
the problème is that FLIRT tools like pelf.exe dose not recognize the CPU type.

What can i do in this case ?

```
 pelf lib/libz.a libz.pat
Fatal [lib/libz.a] (adler32.c.obj): Unknown processor type 39
```

**Update** 
I found a plugin called ida2pat that can generate . Pat file from ida.
I can generate Sig file from .pat files But i can not use them . when i load a file in ida pro with my new CPU module and try to load the signiture the signiture is empty (I guess that ida is filtring signutures with cpu type )

How to tell Sigmake about the CPU type . the sigmake tool has - p option that normally sets the cpu type but i am not able to use it correctly . ida has the same command line switch - p that can be used like this - pmipsel (cpu is mipsel ) . But in sigmake it gives " ill processor id " error. 
i tried using my cpu id defined in the cpu module but ida dose not show the sig file

Answer (score 1):

IDAPython - you can automate almost everything in IDA with IDAPython or IDC.
The hard part is that it's not very well explained. There are a few things that can help:

- All menu actions can be linked to IDC funtion via the IDA configuration files found in the cfg directory inside the IDA installation path (3 files starting with ida)
- Read inside the source files. They're fairly well documented.
- Read the IDA Pro book second edition

Apart from that you might even be able to do it without the IDA GUI: http://www.hexblog.com/?p=128